# CSS clearfix not working, why?

Tags: html, css, css-float, clearfix

I am creating a webpage with a responsive nav. I think I am almost there, except from a very confusing clearfix issue..

I tried to replicate the error in jsfiddle, but was unfortunately not able to. That is why I uploaded the whole webpage to [this](http://testurl321.site50.net/clearfix/base.html) link.

The problem is that when the page is re-sized, the responsive nav-toggle is placed beneath the header, instead of on top of the header. This is due to the floating property = right in the nav-toggle class.

I have been trying to add a clearfix:

```
.clearfix:after { 
  content: "."; 
  display: block; 
  height: 0; 
  clear: both; 
  visibility: hidden; 
}
.clearfix { 
  display: inline-block;  
}
* html .clearfix {  
  height: 1%;  
} /* Hides from IE-mac \*/
.clearfix {  
  display: block;  
}
```

to the parent div like this:

```
<div class="row head clearfix"> <!-- Start Row -->
```

and also like this:

```
<nav class="nav-collapse clearfix"> 
  <ul class="clearfix">
```

Still, the responsive nav-toggle is placed beneath the header when the screen (<768px) is re-sized.

Can anybody tell me how to solve this, small, but annoying problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is divs generally cover entire row so automatically the next element follows below them. To achieve what you want simply add

```
.logo-small{
   float:left;
}
```

and position your nav-toggle.

```
.nav-toggle {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: You beat me to the exact answer by 10 seconds :P 
All though I don't understand that `.logo-small` has been given `display:inline-block`, and the box-model shows it not taking the full width.

Comment: Oh lord! That solved the problem.. I had the float: left on the img, not the div itself. Now I don't need clearfix at all! Thank you very much!

Comment: if display was block instead it should work again @AnkurAnand

Comment: Ya I tried display:block. I just couldn't figure out the `display:inline-block` and why it takes the whole width.

Comment: @AnkurAnand Ah, I really don't know why they work that way I only know how they work. Best look at a documentation I presume.